# Putting Namespaces into Different XML Tags in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I have an xml file in `tmp/Program.ev3p`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SourceFile Version="1.0.2.10" xmlns="http://www.ni.com/SourceModel.xsd">
    <Namespace Name="Project">
        <VirtualInstrument IsTopLevel="false" IsReentrant="false" Version="1.0.2.0" OverridingModelDefinitionType="X3VIDocument" xmlns="http://www.ni.com/VirtualInstrument.xsd">
            <FrontPanel>
                <fpruntime:FrontPanelCanvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:fpruntime="clr-namespace:NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.FrontPanelRuntime;assembly=NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.FrontPanelRuntime" xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:NationalInstruments.SourceModel.Designer;assembly=NationalInstruments.SourceModel" x:Name="FrontPanel" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.CanSnapToObjects="True" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.SnapToObjects="True" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.ShowSnaplines="True" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.ShowControlAdorners="True" Width="640" Height="480" />
            </FrontPanel>
            <BlockDiagram Name="__RootDiagram__">
                <StartBlock Id="n1" Bounds="0 0 70 91" Target="X3\.Lib:StartBlockTest">
                    <ConfigurableMethodTerminal>
                        <Terminal Id="Result" Direction="Output" DataType="Boolean" Hotspot="0.5 1" Bounds="0 0 0 0" />
                    </ConfigurableMethodTerminal>
                    <Terminal Id="SequenceOut" Direction="Output" DataType="NationalInstruments:SourceModel:DataTypes:X3SequenceWireDataType" Hotspot="1 0.5" Bounds="52 33 18 18" />
                </StartBlock>
            </BlockDiagram>
        </VirtualInstrument>
    </Namespace>
</SourceFile>
```

I am trying to modify it with the following code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('tmp/Program.ev3p')
root = tree.getroot()

namespaces = {'http://www.ni.com/SourceModel.xsd': '' ,
              'http://www.ni.com/VirtualInstrument.xsd':'',
              'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation':'',
              'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml':'x',
              'clr-namespace:NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.FrontPanelRuntime;assembly=NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.FrontPanelRuntime':'fpruntime',
              'clr-namespace:NationalInstruments.SourceModel.Designer;assembly=NationalInstruments.SourceModel': 'Model',
              }

for uri, prefix in namespaces.items():
    ET._namespace_map[uri] = prefix

diagram = root[0][0][1]
elem = ET.Element('Data')
diagram.append(elem)

tree.write('tmp/Program.ev3p',"UTF-8",xml_declaration=True)
```

After running the code, my xml file contains:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SourceFile xmlns="http://www.ni.com/SourceModel.xsd" xmlns="http://www.ni.com/VirtualInstrument.xsd" xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:NationalInstruments.SourceModel.Designer;assembly=NationalInstruments.SourceModel" xmlns:fpruntime="clr-namespace:NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.FrontPanelRuntime;assembly=NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.FrontPanelRuntime" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Version="1.0.2.10">
    <Namespace Name="Project">
        <VirtualInstrument IsReentrant="false" IsTopLevel="false" OverridingModelDefinitionType="X3VIDocument" Version="1.0.2.0">
            <FrontPanel>
                <fpruntime:FrontPanelCanvas Height="480" Width="640" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.CanSnapToObjects="True" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.ShowControlAdorners="True" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.ShowSnaplines="True" Model:DesignerSurfaceProperties.SnapToObjects="True" x:Name="FrontPanel" />
            </FrontPanel>
            <BlockDiagram Name="__RootDiagram__">
                <StartBlock Bounds="0 0 70 91" Id="n1" Target="X3\.Lib:StartBlockTest">
                    <ConfigurableMethodTerminal>
                        <Terminal Bounds="0 0 0 0" DataType="Boolean" Direction="Output" Hotspot="0.5 1" Id="Result" />
                    </ConfigurableMethodTerminal>
                    <Terminal Bounds="52 33 18 18" DataType="NationalInstruments:SourceModel:DataTypes:X3SequenceWireDataType" Direction="Output" Hotspot="1 0.5" Id="SequenceOut" />
                </StartBlock>
            <Data /></BlockDiagram>
        </VirtualInstrument>
    </Namespace>
</SourceFile>
```

I need the namespaces to be in the tags they were registered in the original file instead of having all of them inside `SourceFile`, is it possible to achieve so in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the undocumented `ElementTree._namespace_map[uri] = prefix` is the older Python version (< 1.3) for namespace assignment to the more current, documented [`ElementTree.register_namespace(prefix, uri)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace). But even this method does not resolve the root issue and docs emphasize this assignment applies globally and replaces any previous namespace or prefix:

> **xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace(prefix, uri)** 
>   Registers a namespace prefix. The registry is global, and any existing
>   mapping for either the given prefix or the namespace URI will be
>   removed. *prefix* is a namespace prefix. *uri* is a namespace uri. Tags
>   and attributes in this namespace will be serialized with the given
>   prefix, if at all possible.

---

To achieve your desired result and because your XML is a bit complex with multiple default and non-default namespaces, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special-purpose language to transform XML files. Python can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with the third-party module, `lxml` (not built-in `etree`). Additionally, XSLT is portable so very code can run in other languages (Java, C#, PHP, VB) and dedicated [processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) (e.g., Saxon, Xalan).

Specifically, you can use a temporary prefix like *doc* to map the default namespace of lowest level parent, *VirtualInstrument* and use this prefix to identify the needed nodes. All other elements are copied over as is with the [identity transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) template. Also, because you are adding an element to the default namespace you can assign it with the `xsl:element` tag.

**XSLT** *(save below as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://www.ni.com/VirtualInstrument.xsd">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:BlockDiagram">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:element name="Data" namespace="http://www.ni.com/VirtualInstrument.xsd"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# LOAD XML AND XSL 
dom = ET.parse('Input.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM INPUT
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# OUTPUT RESULT TREE TO CONSOLE
print(newdom) 

# SAVE RESULT TREE AS XML
with open('Output.xml','wb') as f:
     f.write(newdom)
```

[XSLT Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZB)